# Loop over HashMaps of HashMaps of HashMaps - Java

Tags: java, loops, dictionary, hashmap, iteration

I worked with Python or other languages that we can work with dictionaries, recently I'm making a code in Java, and I'm using the HashMaps Collections, for some reason I need to create a HashMap that contains objects as another HashMaps or String, And into those HashMaps there are more HashMaps with sub-HashMaps, let me show you the structure:

```
 HashMap1{
    "str" : "Something",
    "HashMap2" : {
        "str" : "It's time to choose",
        "HashMap3" : {
            "str" : "I love playing Dota",
            "HashMap4" : {...}   
         }
     }    
 }
```

I don't know if it's the better performance or if there are any another collections that is better for me to use, now I wrote a lot of line of code using this collections, and I get to the point that I need to iterate it.

How can I make that? Using recursion?

Comment: For what purpose do you have this structure? You need to mention it to get some other suggestions.

Comment: Too bad you can't parse this JSON as JSON and are forced to do all that manually ...........

Comment: I have a lot of HashMaps like this, but some with more or less elements. And when I want to analyze all HashMaps some returns NullPointerException for that reason I need to create an static attribute that contains something like "frame" or "initial structure", but this "frame" it's being update with each HashMap (only the structure not the value). In another words, I need to have the static structure to leave all HashMaps equal. @SanketMakani

Comment: No Tom, this is not a JSON, is a HashMap, but I wrote the structure only. @Tom